# Cancel an async request with useInterval hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Cancelling a request is super easy with useEffect's cleanup

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;
  fetchData(id).then(data => {
    if (!ignore) {
      setData(data);
    }
  });
  return () => (ignore = true);
}, [id]);
```

I want to do something similar but I need to poll for the data with [useInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

I want to poll for data with `fetchData(id)` and ignore the returned response if the request had fired but the `id` changed before the response resolved.

Comment: I think you should abort the old request not ignore the response. Take look on AbortController

Comment: @MateuszKrzyżanowski what profit do you see in cancelling request over ignoring response?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the idea. You want regularly fetch data for the same id? if yes, what should happen if response did not come in time and you have to send new request(what to do with potential race conditions)? Or do you want debounce fetching to save some server's CPU?

Comment: @skyboyer you are not blocking the server time, your application doesn't care about data that is not important for it and the code is simpler, it is easier to debug because you see an aborted request in the network tools and you are sure that your app is free from the race conditions

Comment: @MateuszKrzyżanowski, I strongly believe server will need some additional code to detect connection closed _before_ sending response(say [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php)). So by default we won't save server time. Sorry for offtop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hack for your particular case

Assuming you're receiving `id` as props or some such, would this work?

```
const Foo = ({ id }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  const passedId = useRef()
  passedId.current = id

  useInterval(() => {
    fetchData(id)
      .then(response => id === passedId.current && setData(response))
  }, 5000)

  // Render some JSX with the data
```

I tested something very similar to this locally and essentially what happens is this:

1. `Foo` receives `id = 6`
2. `6` is stored in `passedId`
3. `useInterval` ticks and we request `id = 6`
4. the component receives `id = 7`
5. `7` is stored in `passedId`
6. the request for `id = 6` completes, but `passedId.current === 7` so `setData` isn't called
7. the request for `id = 7` completes, `id === passedId.current` and `setData` is called

### Getting something like this into `useInterval`

#### Note - not tested

Maybe the reason why cancelling an effect is so easy is because the function returns its own cleanup so `ignore` doesn't have to be scoped externally. But `setInterval` doesn't allow return values. We *might* be able to get around this using a `setTimeout` instead:

```js
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  useEffect(() => {
    let cleanup
    let id
    function tick() {
      cleanup = callback()
      id = setTimeout(tick, delay)
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      tick()
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(id)
        cleanup && cleanup()
      }
    }
    return () => cleanup && cleanup()
  }, [callback, delay])
```

One catch with this is that now we have `callback` in the dependency array so the callback given to `useInterval` should be created using `useCallback`:

```js
const Foo = ({ id }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  const pollData = useCallback(() => {
    let shouldUpdate = true

    fetchData(id).then(resp => shouldUpdate && setData(resp))

    return () => shouldUpdate = false
  }, [id])

  useInterval(pollData, 5000)

  // Render some JSX with the data
```

1. When `useInterval` is called, we setup a `useEffect` that executes `callback`
2. When `callback` executes, the return value (the cleanup for it) is stored in `cleanup` which is scoped to the effect and a `setTimeout` is setup to re-execute in `delay` milliseconds
3. If `callback` changes (i.e. we get a new `id`), then we clear the timeout and run the cleanup for the previous callback
4. After `delay` milliseconds, `tick` is executed again

Comment: I have a little doubt. Assuming that the id has not been changed, after the first pollData request is sent, the second pollData request is sent immediately. At this time, both cleanup and id correspond to the second request. If both pollData requests are not resolved at this time and the id changes at this time, does it mean that only the second pollData request can be cleared, and the first pollData will still execute the setData function

Comment: @weiwang Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your example but the proposed code could very well be wrong! Could you help me understand why the second `pollData` request would be sent immediately?

That being said ... I feel like the proposed code is wrong because I don't see how it would call `tick` the first time :-\ Unfortunately I've been out of the React game for a couple years so I'm not sure I can properly test/edit this. Maybe I should just remove the proposal?

Comment: I added a call to `tick()` in the `useEffect`. That seems to make slightly more sense to me but I'm happy to get more feedback!

Comment: Hi, Mark. Thank you very much for your reply. I am a newcomer to react hook, so my opinion may not be correct. My concern is that if two fetchData requests have already been sent at this time, but the two fetchData requests are very slow, and the data has not yet been obtained. At this time, if the id changes later, the cleanup logic will be executed, but I think the value of shouldUpdate of the second fetchData request will be changed to false, but the value of shouldUpdate of the first fetchData will not be changed to false. I don't know if I am right, want to discuss with you.

Comment: @weiwang Ah well I think the thing here is that `fetchData` called in a `useEffect` and the return value of the `useEffect` is a function which calls `cleanup`. The return value of an effect runs before the next effect starts. So, hopefully, before a second `fetchData` request was made, the first `cleanup` function would be run and `shouldUpdate` would be set to false for the first request.

Comment: Hi, Mark. Thank you again for your reply. My question now is that I see that the tick() function is a recursively called function, so I think that the fetchData function will be executed multiple times in the same useEffect. So I don't understand why you said that the fetchData function will only be executed once in a useEffect. I don’t know if my thoughts are correct, and I hope you can understand if it is completely wrong.

Comment: @weiwang Ah! I think I understand your question now. I believe `useInterval` _assumes_ that the interval of repetition is longer than the time it takes for `callback` to execute. So, with just `useInterval` by itself, only one `fetchData` call should be in flight at a time. Furthermore, if props change before `fetchData` has completed and there is a new `id` prop, the old effect will be cleaned up before the new `fetchData` call is made. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the useInterval I came up with

```
function (callback, options, cleanup) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (options.delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, options.delay);
      return () => {        
        clearInterval(id);
        cleanup && cleanup();
      }
    }
    return () => cleanup && cleanup();
  }, [options]);
}
```

And I use it so

```
const [fetchOptions, setFetchOptions] = useState({delay: 5000, id: 'someid'});

let ignore = false;
useInterval(
  () => {
    fetchData(fetchOptions.id).then(data => {
      if (!ignore) {
        setData(data);
      }
    });
  },
  fetchOptions,
  () => (ignore = true),
);
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to write this. My concern is with the `ignore` variable being scoped to the context of the function/component. In the code example of the question, the ignore variable is inside the useEffect and feels cleaner.

The downside of this approach is that fetchOptions needs to be a useState variable otherwise it would reset the useInterval hook on every render if it was just a constant in the function.

Comment: Just a quick question - it looks like `delay` changed from being a positional argument to being a named parameter in an object. Was it the intent that `ignore` would be inside `fetchOptions`? If not, can `useCallback` handle creating a new fetcher when the `id` changes and then `delay` and `cleanup` remain positional?

Comment: Oh, is `fetchOptions` intended to start a new interval when `delay` OR `id` changes?

Comment: Yes, that was the intention, start a new interval when delay or id changes.